# Не отображается pdf файл

Tags: php, mysql

Не отображается pdf файл, хотя передаю в header content-type pdf

```
<?php
include "bd.php";
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if ($id > 0) {
        $login = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT login FROM bills WHERE id = '$id'"))['login'];
        if ($login == $_SESSION['login']) {
            $document = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT file FROM bills WHERE id = '$id'"))['file'];
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");
            $file = fopen("$document", "r");
            $content = "";
            while ($f = fgets($file, 4096)) {
                $content .= $f;
            }
            echo $content;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: С проверкой на логин все хорошо

Comment: `$file = fopen("$document", "r");
            $content = "";
            while ($f = fgets($file, 4096)) {
                $content .= $f;
            }
            echo $content;` вот это всяко поменяйте на `readfile($document);`